# Django Music API

Tags: django

I'm currently learning django and working on my project. My project involves sharing my composed music and allowing free downloads to people. Is there an API for django that can enable me to upload my music and enable users to download at will?

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general I agree with Rajat, what you are trying to achieve (at least the way you described it), can be done with standard Django forms and file handling. However, this [app](https://github.com/rizumu/django-podcasting) should have already built in a lot of the stuff you require.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an API to upload files to your servers.You only need a form to do that.And for enabling your users to download content,you only need links to the files.You can use some api to let only authenticated users download the content from your site.

Comment: thanks but what about the ability to play the music online? is that in django too? or is there an api for that?

Comment: Well,Django can only stream music to your user's computer.Then it's the responsibility of your front end to play the music.You can easily play music using various jQuery plugins available or some HTML5 player.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file user submitted file in media folder
We then later you can  locate it's path to make available for your users